# sql insert into database if sum of total column is greater than 10

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using SQL.
I have table name [TEST] with an integer column [column1].

I want to insert data to [column1] until the records reach the sum of 100.
If the sum would go above 100, the SQL query should not insert the record.

It means that, before executing the insert statement, SQL query should check the sum of the available data. If data is smaller than 100, then it will insert. Else, it will not insert.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Any effort so far? Sounds not a hard problem to me. Where do you keep your inserted values? A `List<int>` or something? Just check the total is bigger than 100 or not before insert operation in a loop for example.. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs.

Comment: you can use triggers, but we need to know more about your problem, code and table structure, can you explain it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following stored procedure for your insert statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertData
(
    @value INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @total INT
    SET @total = ISNULL((SELECT SUM([columnName]) FROM [tableName]),0)

    IF (@total + @value) <= 100
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [tableName] VALUES (@value)
        END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in oracle DB, should work in msql or any other database

`Case` statement syntax might differ though! but same logic in general

```
INSERT INTO TEST (COLUMN1)
SELECT [COULMN1 VALUE HERE] FROM DUAL
/*The condition that will check if inserting allowed or not*/
WHERE 
1 = (SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(column1) + [COULMN1 VALUE HERE] >= 100 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM TEST)
```

**Note:** using this solution you will spare you from the need to write any stored procedures.

Comment: You didn't add 'to be inserted' value on your where clause. Also, it is not necessary to use stored procedure to use variables in MS SQL.

Comment: @sismsim, I think you need to review the problem further. It seems you have missed out some important details :)

Comment: @Tonned, you are right, edited, in my where statement I should have used sum instead of count, but the idea of the solution is clear, you can use any filter in the where statement that fits your needs.

Comment: @Vinvinvinvin, edited my answer, although as I stated in the previous comment, the idea is the same, the use of a dummy table with a dummy where statement. the rest in the where statement could be anything, it could be a very complicated where statement with joins and stuff, or could be case when 1 = 1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using store procedure to insert data in my table..

```
insert into  FundTransfer_Log values (@id,@data);
```

This statements is a loop which check all the data in the table(Table contains more than 200 records).
 First , the above insert statement sums the total of @data to check whether it is smaller than 100. If it returns smaller than 100 then it will insert all the record with the id else it will not insert.

Comment: Is this supposed to be your answer to your problem? or an update with your question?